# Can GitHub automatically merge branches?

Tags: git, github

We want to automatically merge out from master to another long-lived branch whenever any changes are committed to master (at the moment, this is a manual process and people forget)

I appreciate that it may not always be possible, owing to merge conflicts, but if it is possible, we'd like it to happen automatically.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can use Github actions now https://github.com/features/actions

Comment: I am curious what you ended up doing (if anything), and if you are happy with your solution, @Kram.

Comment: @theartofrain - looks like GitHub actions may be the only way still. There is a good example below which I intend to try

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### You can use GitHub Actions since Aug 13, 2019

This method will merge your branch with the master without the requirement to create pull requests manually.

Just create `.github/workflows/automerge.yml` file in your repo with this content:

```
name: Automerge

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    # You can setup schedule here
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'

env:
  # replace "github_username" with your GitHub username
  # replace "github.com/username/repo.git" with your GitHub repo path
  # do NOT replace ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}, GitHub will take care of it
  MY_REPO: https://github_username:${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}@github.com/username/repo.git

  # replace "long-lived_branch_name" with your branch name
  MY_BRANCH: long-lived_branch_name

  # replace it with the path to master repo
  MASTER_REPO: https://github.com/username/master_repo.git

  # replace "master" with your master branch name
  MASTER_BRANCH: master

jobs:
  merge:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Merge with master
      run: |
        git clone ${{env.MY_REPO}} -b ${{env.MY_BRANCH}} tmp
        cd tmp
        git config user.name "Automerge Bot"
        git config user.email "bot@example.com"
        git config pull.rebase false
        git pull ${{env.MASTER_REPO}} ${{env.MASTER_BRANCH}}
        git push
```

- replace "github_username" with your GitHub username
- replace "github.com/username/repo.git" with your GitHub repo path
- replace "long-lived_branch_name" with your branch name
- replace "master" with your master branch name
- edit "cron" line to adjust the schedule

Also, don't forget to enable this workflow on the "Actions" page of your repo. You can run it manually too. You'll receive an e-mail from GitHub if merge was failed.

Comment: this works well! Only thing I changed was the "on" to use "push" trigger so that it runs automatically each time changes are pushed to master

Answer (score 5):

### Is available since 2020-12-16

The native GitHub Auto-Merge was introduced on GitHub Universe 2 days ago.

[How to active them?](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/managing-auto-merge-for-pull-requests-in-your-repository) Go to *Settings* of your repository, e.g. https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/settings, then ↓

[image]

---

*Tip: do you want to prevent merged branch piling up? Enable autobranch removal too*

[Source](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2020/12/08/github-introduces-dark-mode-and-auto-merge-pull-request/)

While it might not be solely what you need to you for your use case, it can be used with GitHub Actions to get there more easily.

Comment: Automatic merging has been introduced: Auto-merge pull requests (#107): when using protected branches. Rolling out over the next couple of weeks, enabled in your repo settings. https://github.blog/2020-12-08-new-from-universe-2020-dark-mode-github-sponsors-for-companies-and-more/

Comment: @00schneider Not yet. There is no clear ETA on public beta.

Comment: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-12-16-pull-request-auto-merge-public-beta/ - it's out

Comment: Im still confused if it will be possible to configure totally automatic merge of PR:s or if this requires someone to manually mark the PR as allowed to auto merge once things are green?

Comment: My use case is bots that i trust

Comment: OP asked that changes from master would be merged to other branches (without a PR). This posted answer is about automatically closing a PR (typically in the direction of other_branch => master).

Comment: @JellicleCat yes you are right. This answer is not correct, however useful the one-off auto merge can be.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using https://github.com/marketplace/actions/merge-pull-requests for a while and it works pretty well. In that page you have the instructions on how to use it.

If you need more specific workflows, you can try https://mergify.io/ also.