# Github: How to auto-merge to development branch from release branch?

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

We recently switch from Bitbucket to Github. One feature we're missing is the ability to create PRs or Auto-merge commits made onto a "release" branch directly to our development branch. We had it set so if a bug was fixed in the "release" branch, which was branched off of development just prior to release, it would auto-create a PR and merge the PR if there were no conflicts.

How are teams using Github to accomplish this? I don't see it as a default configuration, but I'm assuming teams are doing something like this as it's pretty common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw answers to a similar question on [Can GitHub automatically merge branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445186/can-github-automatically-merge-branches) . I think it will solve your problem. It seems Github has introduced a new auto merge feature in 2020 december.