# Update automatically git branches from another

Tags: git, gitlab

I have three branches *main*, *A* and *B*. When I commit and push some code on my *main* branch I want to update/merge content of *main* into *A* and *B* automatically.

Is there a simple way to do this with git or gitlab? Or Do I have to use a webhook and shell scripts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445186/can-github-automatically-merge-branches

Comment: I wonder why not you just use `main`.

Comment: I will explain more: 

Main is a branch where I push only "valid" features mening tested features.
A is a daily updated branch with all small fixes.
and B is a monthly branch containing heavy features to validate.

A and B are manually merged with Main branch.
But I wish to update those branches with Main automatically.

Comment: You've tagged your question both "gitlab" and "github" -- which one are you using? In either case, there are existing answers to this question for both platforms.