# Automate github enterprise pull request and merge

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions

I am using github enterprise repository for storing my project code.

Is there any way to create a pull request and merge to another branch, whenever there is a code merge into **main** branch ?
This activity will help to reduce manual effort to create a new branch from main for any new changes.

Is there any way in github itself ?
Or Is there any way using azure devops(CI/CD) pipelines?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need another branch? It sounds like you could probably get what you want by looking at the log/reflog of just your main branch.

Comment: My requirement is to update another branch whenever there is a change in main branch. Just like a reverse merge from main to an existing branch, so that I can work on that branch directly for any new changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can GitHub automatically merge branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445186/can-github-automatically-merge-branches)